# H2O model deployment into .Net

Tags: java, c#, random-forest, h2o

I am using H2O, Randomforest for 36 class classification problem. this model works really good and we decide to deploy this model for our real world application which is in C#.

for this, I had to download the POJO format (which is java), covert it to C#, make a dll and use the dll in our C# application. it works!

BUT is there any way to make the whole process easier? or maybe in future, can H2O provide randomforest or any other models deployed in other languages rather than java?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, today this is unsupported in H2O-3.